# How to customize Model or Manager that change the data format in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I hava an `Article` model ,contains a `title` column,which can be stored mix with white space,what i want is that ,every time i query an article,space in `title` content could be repaced with dash,for url friendly.

**models.py:**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0,'on'),
        (1,'off')
    )
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text='primary key',auto_created=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='articles', help_text='foreigner key reference Category')
    #author = models.ForeignKey(myadmin.User, help_text='foreigner key reference myadmin User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='article title')
    description = models.TextField(help_text='article brief description')
    content = models.TextField(help_text='article content')
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0,help_text='like numbers')
    secretcode = models.CharField(max_length=512,help_text='who has the code can scan')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS,help_text='status of the article')
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,help_text='time that first created')
    modifytime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,help_text='time when modified')

    articles = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'article'
```

my view.py:

```
def get(self,request):
        offset = int(request.GET.get('offset', 0))
        category = request.GET.get('category')
        end = offset+10
        articlecatalogs = Article.articles.filter(category__name=category)[offset:end]
```

i was thinking creating a custom Manager and define a method to transform the data,but the query conditions needed are from request,in here,i don't know how to do it ?can someone help me?

Comment: Can you clear your question little bit more ? why you need title in slug and where you want to use this ?

Comment: my title has white space,there is a article list in my page,if not dealing with that,in my frontend page,it is hard to use,although i use title to query the detailed article content,so i want to replace the white space to dash,for example,in db:**this is my article**,when i query them ,it should be **this-is-my-article**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use slug filed as well and overwrite your save method for save slug something like this :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField("slug")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='articles', help_text='foreigner key reference Category')
  -- more fields --

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
             self.slug = self.title.strip(" ").replace(' ','-')
        super(Article, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def get_title(self):
        """ write python code for remove extra spaces so can can dispay your tile in html and call this method with instance when you want to print title """
        return new_title_without_extra_spaces
```

for details page you can use slug value for get a instance. Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: i am using django-rest-framework serializer,can it be integrate with that?is it a new column in db?